# Sufficient for analyticity

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $f$ be complex valued function such that $f(z)=U(x,y)+iV(x,y)$,
 Here $U(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ is given,
Now here it is easy to find out $V(x,y)=2xy + C$, $C$ is any arbitrary complex constant,
Now my doubt is that is there unique $V(x,y)$ for making $f$ analytic or is there infinite number of $V(x,y)$ (for the arbitrary complex constant) for making $f$ analytic?
I am here little bit confused.
Please what is right!
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the functions $U(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ and $V(x,y)=2xy+C$ satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations, thus $f=U+iV$ is analytic for all constant $C$.

Note that $$f=x^2-y^2+i(2xy+C)=(x+iy)^2+iC$$
i.e. $f=z^2+C'$ which is analytic, of course.

Comment: ,,So there are infinitely many choices of V.

Comment: @Subhajit Yes infinitely many.